# Problems with scrollview, only in the finished app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

I uploaded my app to app store some month ago, but now I got some complaints that the app crashes when they enter a specific place in the app(where yuo see a picture which you can zoom in and out, and scroll). On my iPhone, I can enter the picture, but the scrolling is weird! I can't scroll to the right and left any more (which is important if you zoom in alot!)... I tried it in the simulator in xcode, but there it all works fine! I have a full version and a lite version.. The problem is in both of them! I have the latest iOS in both my iPhone and simulator!

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Oh I can't scroll up and down either!

Comment: The scroll seems to be the least of your worries,  this may be fixed by either allowing the UIScrollView to scroll (`setScrollEnabled:`), or ensuring that the contentView is indeed larger than the scrollview.  The crash could be related, it may not be, you would need to identify on what line the crash occurs and provide more information if you're still unsure of what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply uploaded the same code to app store again, then it worked!